# How does the voice recognition recognises a difference between 5 and five?

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

I'm trying to make a voice calculator and it works in like 70% but the problem is that sometimes instead of 5 it sees a string as five and then it gives me NaN, since it cant add a non number to a number. is there any shortcut of getting the recognition better without having to check every number.

I just check the +-*/ sign and then do the maths with the outer strings (first and last until a blank space).

```
const content =document.querySelector('.content');

const SpeechRecognition=window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
const recognition=new SpeechRecognition();

recognition.onstart=function(){
    console.log('voice activated talk');
};

recognition.onresult=function(event){
    const current=event.resultIndex;
const transcript=event.results[current][0].transcript;
//content.textContent=transcript;
readoutloud(transcript);
};

btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    recognition.start();
});


let cifra=0;
let del='';
function readoutloud(message){
const speech= new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
speech.text="I don't know what you said.";
console.log(message);
if(message.includes('are you'))
{}
...
//here it sees what is in the string and then i manipulate with data
```

Comment: Why should this be a problem of the "voice recognition". There's simply no difference between 5 and five.

Comment: A voice recognition is always going to return characters in its response. You are just lucky that you got single character of 5 which can be convert into a number.  In the first version of your application, you should build a dictionary of words to represent the actions you want to provide. Then perform said action.

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to convert numbers like `ten` to `10` etc.

use this library

```
var WtoN = require('words-to-num');
WtoN.convert('one hundred and 42'); // => 142
```

Comment: thank you,  so i should then just check if ((int(message) !=message) if the parseint cant convert and then try to convert it that way?